# IDA decompile binary file

Tags: ida

how can I decompile a binary file using IDA? I tried opening it and it said it cannot find the entry point automatically and I don't know where to find it,

Comment: What type of binary (cpu type, platform/OS it was running on)? Where does the binary come from?

Comment: Do you have the IDA Pro decompiler plugin?  It is a separate product.

Comment: @Robert I'm using windows 10 and the binary file is an ex5 file from MetaTrader5. I wrote a small indicator a few months back and lost the mql5 file when I changed computers.

Comment: @fpmurphy yes I have the plugin. I recently discovered IDA pro and haven't found my feet yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to analyze an ex5 file which is a MetaTrader5 file. That is not what IDA is for, that file is not an executable most likely. If the format isn't documented you can analyze the Application itself to figure out how it's made up, but most likely it's easier to just do it again.